# how to install mono on ubuntu 18.04

Tags: mono

this is the code that i'm trying to use

```
sudo apt install gnupg ca-certificates
sudo apt-key adv --keyserver hkp://keyserver.ubuntu.com:80 --recv-keys 3FA7E0328081BFF6A14DA29AA6A19B38D3D831EF
echo "deb https://download.mono-project.com/repo/ubuntu stable-bionic main" | sudo tee /etc/apt/sources.list.d/mono-official-stable.list
sudo apt update
```

however, when i enter the first line of code, i get the following error

```
E: Malformed line 4 in source list /etc/apt/sources.list.d/mono-official-stable.list (type)
E: The list of sources could not be read.
E: Malformed line 4 in source list /etc/apt/sources.list.d/mono-official-stable.list (type)
E: The list of sources could not be read.
```

Answer (score 0):

maybe there's a typo in your list file or the key is invalid or have been changed, you can check it with:

```
cd /etc/apt/sources.list.d
gedit mono-official-stable.list # read only
```

if you have the right key or find the typo try:

```
sudo gedit mono-official-stable.list
```

edit, remove or comment the line 4